# FBA SharePoint 2010 and login in Word

Tags: forms-authentication, claims-based-auth, security-token-service

I have tried to get into Claim based authentication using FBA as with AspNetSqlRoleProvider and AspNetSqlMembershipProvider, I got it up and running. But there is one issue I can't get my head around. It is that I need to login when opening a word document if I do not check automatically log me in. Is this by design? Does the users have to check of “remember me” to prevent the call to login in word? How is the security toking used by SharePoint/Word when first authenticated and the cookie is set, is it getting the user name and password and sending a new request back to the provider or is it just using it locally to authenticate word?

And are there any blogs that can explain how this works, so I can get a better understanding of how Claim based authentication works in detail?

This is all new to me but I relay want to understand how it all work.

[Edit]
I’m setting the cookie using SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionToken and I works well in my developer environment. I login and when I open a document in Office I do not get the login window. I can see that the FedAuth is set using Fiddler. But it does not work in the Production farm, the difference it uses https. When I check in fiddler I cannot see that the FedAuth cookie is set, and the users has to login when opening office documents (They are using web apps, but still). I did not set up the farm, so I do not know if this was turn of somehow or that something is set up wrong. Is there some settings or configurations I can check to find the reason why the cookie is not set (or any other reason why users has to login when opening Office applications)? (Maybe this should be a new question, but still think it’s a hard topic to understand??)

Comment: I don't know the specific reason why, but I can tell you as much as users will need to use the *Remember me* option when they login for this **not** to occur when opening Word (or similar doc) files

Comment: @Ziga do you know how the check box is implemented what do it do in code when checked?

Comment: Practically it just places a cookie in the browser like any other *Remember me* you see on other sites.

Comment: Sharepoint Total waste trying to survive with sharepoint for the last 10 years and they always leave these small issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading [Geoff Varosky's blog](http://sharepointyankee.com/2011/07/22/sign-me-in-automatically-in-forms-authentication/) and [MSDN on Claims-Based Single Sign-On for Microsoft SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh446525.aspx) and [the Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx), too. There may be some hints.